# MVC3 routing remembers last parameter value when using UrlParameter.Optional

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, routes

I have problem with optional parameter for one of the routes. Route looks like that:

```
            routes.MapRoute(
            "VideoList", // Route name
            "VideoList/{page}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Video", action = "VideoList" , page = UrlParameter.Optional}
        );
```

It works fine when used first time:

```
@Html.RouteLink("Video", "VideoList", null, new { id = "idVideo", @class = "menu-item" })
```

Controller action gets NULL in place of page parameter and I handle rest within the action.

Then, I play with the web page and I try this same routing again, this time specifying 'page' param, lets say it carries value 7.

```
@Html.RouteLink("Video", "VideoList", new { page = 7 }, new { id = "idVideo", @class = "menu-item" })
```

It works as expected as well, but when again I try to use route without 'page' specified it carries because of some reason again value used for this parameter last time, which is 7

Not sure why. I would expect it to work as first time by passing null to the controller for this parameter

I will provide more info if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's how routing works. You need to explicitly set the parameter if you don't want the RouteLink fetching it from the current request route values:

```
@Html.RouteLink("Video", "VideoList", new { page = "" }, new { id = "idVideo" })
```

This will always generate `/VideoList` url. If you don't explicitly set the `page` parameter to an empty string (as in your first example), then the helper will analyze the current request routing values when generating the link. And if the current url is `/VideoList/7`, then the helper will preserve all route values and generate `/VideoList/7`.

Comment: Thank you Darin. At some point I was trying assigning null to page param within RouteLink. It was quite close :-)